# the semantics of javax.comm.CommPort enableReceiveThreshold(1) and enableReceiveTimeout

Tags: java, serial-port

I have used RXTX and PureJavaComm many times over the years. I have this code in my application:

```
    SerialPort port = /* code to get serial port instance here */
    port.setInputBufferSize(65536);
    port.enableReceiveThreshold(1);
    port.enableReceiveTimeout(10);
```

(1 character threshold, 10ms timeout) and I have vague memories of fine-tuning this until I arrived at the above formula, but shame on me,  I didn't make any notes of why it is this way.

My intent was to respond to an `InputStream.read()` call with a minimum blocking delay if no data has been received, otherwise return as many characters as are already received.

What I don't remember is why/whether the call to `enableReceiveThreshold(1)` is necessary. **If there's already a receive timeout, what's the difference between `enableReceiveThreshold(1)` and `disableReceiveThreshold()`?**

---

PureJavaComm has this code for Windows in `src/jtermios/windows/JTermiosImpl.java`, where `vmin` is the `receiveThreshold` and `vtime` is the `receiveTimeout`, so the [`COMMTIMEOUTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363190(v=vs.85).aspx) structure gets different values if you compare `vmin=0` to `vmin=1`: (some detailed discussion in [How do I use COMMTIMEOUTS to wait until bytes are available but read more than one byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390151/how-do-i-use-commtimeouts-to-wait-until-bytes-are-available-but-read-more-than-o) )

```
        COMMTIMEOUTS touts = port.m_Timeouts;
        // There are really no write timeouts in classic unix termios
        // FIXME test that we can still interrupt the tread
        touts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
        touts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
        if (vmin == 0 && vtime == 0) {
            // VMIN = 0 and VTIME = 0 => totally non blocking,if data is
            // available, return it, ie this is poll operation
            touts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
            touts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
            touts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
        }
        if (vmin == 0 && vtime > 0) {
            // VMIN = 0 and VTIME > 0 => timed read, return as soon as data is
            // available, VTIME = total time
            touts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
            touts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = vtime;
            touts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
        }
        if (vmin > 0 && vtime > 0) {
            // VMIN > 0 and VTIME > 0 => blocks until VMIN chars has arrived or  between chars expired, 
            // note that this will block if nothing arrives
            touts.ReadIntervalTimeout = vtime;
            touts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
            touts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
        }
        if (vmin > 0 && vtime == 0) {
            // VMIN > 0 and VTIME = 0 => blocks until VMIN characters have been
            // received
            touts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
            touts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
            touts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
        }
        if (!SetCommTimeouts(port.m_Comm, port.m_Timeouts))
            port.fail();
```

Answer (score 3):

Aha. The [javax.comm.CommPort API says this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/CommPort.html#getInputStream()):

[image]

So you pick the blocking behavior as per this spec.

Comment: sigh. isn't it great that we can't use table markup in SO?