# serial port: ReadFile and CloseHandle

Tags: c++, windows, api, serial-port, readfile

I want to read a serial port's incoming data and process them (Windows: native C++). But I have two problems with this:

1- What should I put as nNumberOfBytesToRead in [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
ReadFile( hCom, buffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, &read, NULL );
```

If I put 50 and 40 bytes arrive, ReadFile won't return. Because it needs 10 more bytes. If I put 1, my application won't be optimized. What's the best number? What should I do?

2- When I want to exit in my application and if no data is coming through serial port, ReadFile will be locked without return. So I can't close it correctly using CloseHandle. How can I force ReadFile to return while waits for data through serial port?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036716/serial-comm-using-writefile-readfile

Answer (score 2):

When you open the port you should be using SetCommTimeouts. The read timeout is like a latency setting: How long ReadFile should wait before returning if the incoming data pauses. Size your buffer and the timeout for the number of milliseconds you are willing to wait before processing whatever it got.

Comment: Yep, another viable option - I've forgot about this one.

Answer (score 1):

1 - there's no best number. You better use another IO strategy, e.g. overlapped IO, to read data from the port. [Here's some sample code.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx)

2 - In this case you can, and should, close it with CloseHandle call. When you do that, any threads blocked on ReadFile or other blocking API involving the handle you just closed will wake up receiving failed result code.