# Writing to serial-port is blocking forever when other thread is waiting in read

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++, serial-port

I made a small program to test my serial class (based on win32 api). One thread is reading from serial-port and writing to stdout, while the other thread (main) is reading from stdin and writing to serial-port. But serial-port writing is blocking forever. If I doesn't start the serial-port reading thread, serial-port writing does not block. I'm using Visual-Studio 2008 on Windows 7. How can I avoid the blocking?

Serial port open:

```
    handle = ::CreateFile(portname,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,//access ( read and write)
        0,    //(share) 0:cannot share the COM port                        
        NULL,    //security  (None)                
        OPEN_EXISTING,// creation : open_existing
        0, //FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL// no templates file for COM port...
        );
```

Serial port write:

```
virtual size_t write(const void * buffer, size_t size)
{
    unsigned long bytesWritten;
    if (!WriteFile(handle, buffer, size, &bytesWritten, NULL))
    {
        throw SystemError("Serial::write(): WriteFile() failed");
    }
    return bytesWritten;
}
```

Serial port read (called from other thread)

```
virtual size_t read(void * buffer, size_t max)
{
    unsigned long bytesRead;
    if (!ReadFile(handle, buffer, max, &bytesRead, NULL))
    {
        throw SystemError("Serial::read(): ReadFile() failed");
    }
    return bytesRead;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036716/serial-comm-using-writefile-readfile) to see if it helps.

Is there any data to be read on the Serial port? I think the call to ReadFile is a blocking call and will not return unless there is something to read.
You could set TimeOut values on it and the function will return and then you will see your write operation continue.

Also, I am not aware of this API completely, but are you not suppose to synchronize access to the serial port in multithreaded context?

You might want to check this link for more information: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx