# ReadFile USB Serial port too slow

Tags: c++, visual-studio, serial-port

I need to save data coming from GPS. I am using windows 7 system and GPS is connected using USB port. I am using visual studio dialog based application

GPS data is something like this

```
"$GPGLL,2219.2500182,N,09019.0118688,E,055547.65,A,A*61"
```

I need to save this data in file. I have thoroughly gone through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036716/serial-comm-using-writefile-readfile.) and have set parameters accordingly.

```
char buffer[56];
```

This is my code to open port

```
    hcomm= CreateFile("COM8",  
                    GENERIC_READ, 
                    0, 
                    NULL, 
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    0,
                    NULL);
if (hcomm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    TRACE("%s","error");
memset(&port, 0, sizeof(port));
port.DCBlength = sizeof(port);
if ( !GetCommState(hcomm, &port))
 TRACE("getting comm state");
 if (!BuildCommDCB("baud=19200", &port))
 TRACE("building comm DCB");
 if (!SetCommState(hcomm, &port))
  TRACE("adjusting port settings");
  timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
  if (!SetCommTimeouts(hcomm, &timeouts))
     TRACE("setting port time-outs.");
```

And am reading data as follows

```
while(loop which executes after every 20 ms) {
 ReadFile(hcomm, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL);
        if ( read ){
        //code to write data to file
               }
```

Though I receive data, speed is terribly low. I receive data at 10 Hz. I want to save data at 50 readings/second.

Can somebody help me ?

**EDIT:**
As per @ Paul R suggestion, I increased baud rate to 115200. Now, it saves data @ 20 messages/second. My GPS supports maximum update rate of 20 Hz and maximum baud rate 115200. If I want to save data @ 50 messages/second, what will I have to do..

For eg, if update rate is 20 Hz, each reading is available for 50 ms. So, if I am reading port after every 20ms, shouldn't it save every entry twice or in appropriate proportion ?

Comment: Read the "Update rate" part of [this web page](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/gps-basics/gps-glossary).

Comment: @HansPassant, please see edit section in question

Comment: If the GPS have a 20Hz update-rate, then that's 20 times per second, which means even if you will be able to read 50 message per second you won't get 50 unique messages. Attempting to read more messages is just a waste of resources.

Answer (score 1):

It's just basic arithmetic. At 19200 bps you can receive around 1920 characters per second (assuming each character = 8 data bits + 1 start bit + 1 stop bit). Your example message above is around 55 characters + line terminators etc, so that means a little over 30 messages per second best case. If you have to send a message to the device in between each received message then it will be even lower. So 50 messages / second is simply not possible at this data rate.

Simple solution: increase the data rate from 19200 bps to something much higher, e.g. 57600 bps.

Comment: Oh..Thank you for pointing out mistake. I increased the baud rate for both GPS and in code. It now saves @ 20 messages/second. The update rate of GPS is 20 Hz max. Is this causing problem now ?