# Getting input buffer length for Windows serial port in C

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

Is there a non-blocking function which returns the current rx queue length of a serial port in Windows, using C?

All examples I've seen simply call `ReadFile` which blocks until the specified timeout, so I was wondering if it's possible to check if there is anything in the buffer before reading?

E.g. I can simply do this for each character:

```
void ReadCharacter(char *theCharacter)
{
   DWORD numBytesRead = 0;

   while (numBytesRead == 0)
   {
        ReadFile(comPorthandle,
               theCharacter,
               sizeof(char),
               &numBytesRead,
               NULL);
   }
}
```

But is it possible to have something like

```
int numBytesRx = GetNumBytesRx(&portHandle);
if (numBytesRx > 0)
    Read(&portHandle, targetBuffer, numBytesRead);
```

Comment: You could use [timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6037377/3436922)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform async IO with COM port via `ReadFile` consider using last parameter of function, `LPOVERLAPPED` and `OVERLAPPED` structure. `OVERLAPPED` is common practice for async IO in Windows.

[Here you can find examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx)

Comment: `ReadFileEx`, rather, if you want a callback.

Comment: @Lundin It is just another way of doing things. I wouldn't say it is easier, as when you want to recieve callback you need your thread to wait in alertable state and you need a separate procedure.

Comment: You should always have a separate thread when doing any form of I/O though. And yeah it tends to get a bit complex.

Answer (score 2):

`ReadFile` will always return whatever is already in the rx buffer. So if you set no timeouts, you'll get the contents instantly.

Though please note that no professional application puts `ReadFile` in a busy-wait loop. Not only will this needlessly use up CPU, it will also block the thread where the loop exists.

So you should put `ReadFile` inside a thread of its own. This is common practice with all I/O functions. This will solve the blocking problem, but you'll still have the problem with high CPU use.

As an alternative you can use what Windows calls "asynchronous I/O" (*), by using the `ReadFileEx` function. It lets you specify a callback function, which will get triggered whenever you actually receive some data.

Now if you combine "asynchronous I/O" with threading, you get a non-blocking communication which consumes no CPU when there is no data to process. Your I/O thread could either wait for I/O with `SleepEx`, or it could WaitFor an event that you set manually from inside the callback.

---

(*) "Asynchronous I/O" is a nonsense Windows term, since technically, all serial port communication is always asynchronous. Would you send data synchronously with no pause in between, there would just be no way for a slow desktop PC to keep up.

Comment: Asynchronous I/O is asynchronous *from the programmer's perspective*, i.e., the transfer of data to or from the buffer the programmer provided occurs asynchronously.  It has nothing to do with what the hardware is doing!

Comment: @HarryJohnston Of course it has everything to do with the hardware, because the bytes appear in the buffer as the hardware dictates. Synchronous/asynchronous communication are clearly defined technical terms. Don't fall into the trap of listening to Microsoft as they try to re-name every single industry de facto standard term in the world to something else.

Comment: @Lundin: well, I am not sure if they were supposed to name it differently, but I don't think it's ambiguous from the API perspective. The fact that `ReadFile` is blocking an intrinsically async operation, and `ReadFileEx` isn't, is definitely good to know when going low level. But  I don't see why what effect it would have on *my* code if `ReadFileEx` was just spawning a background thread and reading a blocking method under the hood?

Comment: @LousyCoder ReadFileEx does not spawn a thread, it just executes a callback function whenever there is data to read. I'm just advising you to put all I/O in a separate thread as that gives you a good program design.

Comment: @Lundin: yes, what I wrote (perhaps I wasn't clear) is that, from the API perspective, it's irrelevant that it *doesn't* spawn a thread. `ReadFile` is the one that is blocking an intrinsically async operation.

Comment: *the bytes appear in the buffer as the hardware dictates* - we're talking about the application's buffer here, not the underlying hardware buffer(s).  The bytes appear in the application's buffer as the *operating system* dictates, and the programmer's choice of a synchronous or asynchronous API determines whether the buffer is used synchronously (only while the API call is in progress) or asynchronously (at an indeterminate future time, independently of what the thread is doing).

Comment: It isn't just Microsoft that uses the word this way, either.    [See definition #2 here,](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/asynchronous) and also the Linux [man page for signal,](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) which includes the phrase "asynchronously catching a signal via a signal handler".  Words *can* legitimately have more than one meaning sometimes.  (I agree that the phrase "asynchronous communication" has an agreed-upon meaning, mind you, but the phrase in question is "asynchronous I/O".  In an API context, not the same thing.)