# Microsoft Windows API Serial ReadFile Producing Unexpected Output

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, arduino

I am currently trying to write a program that will read Bluetooth output from an Arduino HC-05 module on a Serial Communications Port.

http://cdn.makezine.com/uploads/2014/03/hc_hc-05-user-instructions-bluetooth.pdf

When I open a Putty terminal and tell it to listen to COM4, I am able to see the output that the program running on the Arduino is printing. 
[image]

[image]

However, when I run the following program to try to process incoming data on the serial port programatically, I get the output shown.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <atltrace.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv[]) {

    HANDLE hComm = CreateFile(
        L"COM4",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        NULL,
        0
    );

    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "Error opening COM4" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD dwRead;

    BOOL fWaitingOnRead = false;

    OVERLAPPED osReader = { 0 };

    char message[100];

    osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (osReader.hEvent == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error creating overlapping event" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    while (1) {

        if (!fWaitingOnRead) {
            if (!ReadFile(
                hComm,
                &message,
                sizeof(message),
                &dwRead,
                NULL
            )) {
                if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                    std::cout << "Communications error" << std::endl;
                    return 3;
                }
            }
            else {
                message[100] = '\0';
                std::cout << message << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have made changes to the handle and the ReadFile function call so that it will be making the calls synchronously in an infinite loop. However, Visual Studio pops up a warning saying that the program has stopped working then asks to debug or close program. My assumption is that it must be stalling somewhere or failing to execute some WindowsAPI function somewhere up the stack.

[image]

Any help, pointers, greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to only print the buffer if the error *is* ERROR_IO_PENDING. You should only print it when there is *no* error, and when you do you should only print `dwRead` bytes. And if the error isn't ERROR_IO_PENDING you should print out what it actually is.

Comment: Printing buffer is in the else logic to the ReadFile failing

Comment: No, it isn't; the `else` pairs with the `if (GetLastError...` not with the `if (!ReadFile...`

Comment: Im stupid. Thank you

Comment: Now that you've removed `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` you should no longer be passing `osReader` to `ReadFile`.

Comment: Not quite a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6036716/179910), but I'd guess the code in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037377/179910) there will work for you anyway.

Comment: @JerryCoffin please put an answer referring to your code and I will credit you with the correct answer. Your code works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least IMO, using overlapped I/O for this job is pretty severe overkill. You *could* make it work, but it would take a lot of extra effort on your part, and probably accomplish very little.

The big thing with using comm ports under Windows is to set the timeouts to at least halfway meaningful values. When I first did this, I started by setting all of the values to `1`, with the expectation that this would sort of work, but probably consume excessive CPU time, so I'd want to experiment with higher values to retain fast enough response, while reducing CPU usage.

So, I wrote [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037377/179910) that just set all the values in the `COMMTIMEOUTS` structure to 1, and setup the comm port to send/read data.

I've never gotten around to experimenting with longer timeouts to try to reduce CPU usage, because even on the machine I was using when I first wrote this (probably a Pentium II, or thereabouts), it was functional, and consumed too little CPU time to care about--I couldn't really see the difference between the machine completely idle, and this transferring data. There might be circumstances that would justify more work, but at least for any need I've had, it seems to be adequate as it is.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `message` has the wrong type.

To contain a string, it should be an array of characters, not an array of pointers to characters.

Additionally, to treat it as a string, you need to set the array element after the last character to `'\0'`. `ReadFile` will put the number of characters it reads into `dwRead`.

Also, it appears that you are not using overlapped I/O correctly. This simple program has no need for overlapped I/O - remove it. (As pointed out by @EJP, you are checking for ERROR_IO_PENDING incorrectly. Remove that too.)

Comment: It freezes when I do that during runtime

Comment: @JackFrye What freezes when you do what?

Comment: I had changed the data to an array of characters 100 in size. I think I was printing the memory address before of the char*. I ensure that the bluetooth connection is working. It seems get to the ReadFile check and freezes then Visual Studio asks if I want to stop or debug. I will update the code. @immibis code is updated

Comment: @JackFrye Do you have any experience with C++?

Comment: Yes. I am surprised I missed that improper logic. I am not familiar with a lot of the data types in windows api. I am also rusty on buffers. Worked briefly with them in C when doing a microcontroller class. Can I simply use the builtin streaming classes to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See comments below, in your program:

```
    if (!fWaitingOnRead) {
        if (!ReadFile(                // here you make a non-blocking read.
            hComm,
            message,
            sizeof(*message),
            &dwRead,
            &osReader
            )) {
                                     // Windows reports you should wait for  input.
                                     //
                if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                 std::cout << "Communications error" << std::endl;
                return 3;
            }
            else {                   // <-- remove this.
                                     // insert call to GetOverlappedcResult here.
                std::cout << message << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;                       // instead of waiting for input, you exit.
}
```

After you call `ReadFile()` you have to insert a call for `GetOverlappedResult(hComm, &osReader, &dwBytesRceived, TRUE)` to wait for the read operation to complete and have some bytes in your buffer.

You will also need to have a loop in your program if you don't want to exit prematurely.

If you do not want to do overlapped i/o (which is a wise decision) , do not pass an OVERLAPPED pointer to ReadFile.  ReadFile will block until it has some data to give you.  You will then obviously not need to call `GetOverlappedresult()`

For the serial port, you also need to fill in a DCB structure. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214(v=vs.85).aspx

You can use `BuildCommDCB()`to initialize it.  There is a link to it in the MS doc, `CallGetCommState(hComm, &dcb)` to initialize the serial port hardware.  The serial port needs to know which baud rate etc. you need for your app.

Comment: I took out the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED and replaced it with a NULL. The program is stalling again. Will I still need the loop and GetOverlappedResult if I set the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED  to NULL on the handle?

Comment: @jackfrye see more of what you need to do to get your serial port working in the answer above .

Comment: My vision is to have my arduino constantly sending sensor data over bluetooth to a com port and have some program that we are talking about now record and crunch that data and send back decisions for the arduino. I am assuming that will include overlapping which might make things harder. Could you include some pseudocode with the GetOverlappedResult() call and the looping structure you had mentioned in a previous comment

Comment: My advice is: do not use overlapped I/O if you are not familiar with windows programming.  Especially if you have a simple answer/response console application.  Make sure you fill in your DCB and initialize the port,.  in an infinite loop, call ReadFile(), crunch your data and call WriteFile,  Keep it simple.  Dealing with overlapped I/O and multithreading takes quite a bit of time when doing from scratch.  I do have some c++ classes that deal with that... I will look for them.

Comment: I am up for the challenge of learning it if you have any material that would help or classes you have used before. I do think it might help though especially to sync this program to the rate of the arduino repeated loop

Comment: Are you planning to make this app a Windows app?  That would be the only good excuse for the extra complexity.  In blocking mode, you do have control of the buffer size, timeouts between packets or even between single bytes that you can tailor to your app.  I did find a set of classes, but it's a bit overkill, I used it to talk to a dozen or so costumes through a bluetooth server.

Comment: No it's not a windows store app. I will look into the blocking architecture given it is much simpler and can be made to be close in efficiency