# write to com port and read answer immediately in c++ windows7

Tags: c++, readfile, createfile, writefile

I have a measurment device and want to make a series of measurments and store them to a file.
For this I need to read out the com port properly. All I get back with this code is some weird signs.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
// opening the serial port
HANDLE hSerial;

fprintf(stderr, "Opening serial port...");
hSerial = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM2",
GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0,
NULL,
OPEN_EXISTING,
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
NULL);

if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    return 1;
} else
    fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");

// settings to communicate with device
DCB dcbSerialParams;
ZeroMemory(&dcbSerialParams, sizeof(dcbSerialParams));
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)) {
    //error getting state
    fprintf(stderr,"error getting state ... ");
}

dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = 9600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)) {
    //error setting state
    fprintf(stderr,"error setting state ...");
}

char out_message[] = "fetch?"; // request for the device to send voltage and 
current
char in_message[32];
DWORD BytesToWrite = sizeof(out_message);
DWORD BytesWritten;
DWORD BytesToRead = sizeof(in_message);
DWORD BytesRead;

WriteFile(hSerial, out_message, BytesToWrite, &BytesWritten, NULL);

ReadFile(hSerial, &in_message, BytesToRead, &BytesRead, NULL);

string buffer;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(in_message); i++) {
    buffer += in_message[i];
}
buffer[sizeof(in_message) - 1] = '\0';

// try outs of different outputs
cout << buffer << "\n";
const char*c = buffer.c_str();
printf("%s\n",c);

CloseHandle(hSerial);
return 0;
}
```

I guess I cannot write to com an read out immediately?
Or is there a mistake in the conversion in_message to buffer?

Comment: The API gives you the BytesRead and BytesWritten parameters for a reason - you need to use them.

Comment: You cannot ignore `BytesRead`.  Serial ports are byte-oriented devices, the only guarantee you have is that it is at least 1.  It very likely is, serial ports are slow.  You must loop until you get them all or receive a terminator ('\n' is common) or whatever other way the device protocol dictates.  And make sure it actually sends characters and not binary data.

Comment: *Nearly* a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6036716/179910 (and chances are pretty good that my answer there will work for you).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks a lot. Your example in the link you gave me works fine and I can study it.