# Data loss via serial port (RS232)

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to read a series of data via serial port. Below are my test scenarios:

***I have a sender (POS terminal) and a receiver (dll) on windows 10. Both connected via RS232 cable (9 pins).***

1. The sender writes 16 bytes of data at one time. The receiver is able to read the data, 1 byte per read, by looping 16 times.
2. The sender writes 114 bytes of data at one time. The receiver is able to read the data , 1 byte per read, by looping 114 times.
3. The sender writes 115 bytes of data at one time. The receiver is able to read the data, 1 byte per read, by looping 115 times. But the last character is lost. In other words, the last character seems to be corrupted.

E.g. Data written: **ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMNO**

I am able to get "**ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTABCDEFGHIJKLMN**" correctly. But the last character **'O'** is corrupted. Instead the data read in place of last character is (ASCII value) 205, 255, 234 etc. The data is not consistent during multiple read attempts.

Can anyone please put some light on this? Can anyone guide me if I am missing something-somewhere?

I referred this article for my project: [Serial Port Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450580.aspx)

`Below is the code snippet:`

```
//Port opening.
HANDLE hPortDailUp = CreateFile(portfinal,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_ALWAYS,
            0,
            NULL);

//Setting COM timeouts.
SetCommMask(hPortDailUp, 0);
SetupComm(hPortDailUp, 2048, 2048);
GetCommTimeouts (hPortDailUp, &commTimeOuts);
commTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 100;
commTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 70;
commTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000; //1000
commTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
commTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
SetCommTimeouts(hPortDailUp, &commTimeOuts);

//Setting port configuration.
DCB PortDCB;
PortDCB.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);

PortDCB.BaudRate = BaudRate;
PortDCB.ByteSize = 8;
PortDCB.Parity = NOPARITY;
PortDCB.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
PortDCB.fOutxCtsFlow = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
PortDCB.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
SetCommState(hPortDailUp, &PortDCB)

//Reading data from serial port.
unsigned char tempRecvBuf[3001] = {'\0'};
ReadFile(hPortDailUp, tempRecvBuf + nBytesRead, 1, &TempLen, NULL);

//PortDCB Value at runtime.
PortDCB {DCBlength=28 BaudRate=115200 fBinary=1 ...}    _DCB
    DCBlength           28          unsigned long
    BaudRate            115200      unsigned long
    fBinary             1           unsigned long
    fParity             0           unsigned long
    fOutxCtsFlow        0           unsigned long
    fOutxDsrFlow        0           unsigned long
    fDtrControl         1           unsigned long
    fDsrSensitivity     0           unsigned long
    fTXContinueOnXoff   0           unsigned long
    fOutX               0           unsigned long
    fInX                0           unsigned long
    fErrorChar          0           unsigned long
    fNull               0           unsigned long
    fRtsControl         0           unsigned long
    fAbortOnError       0           unsigned long
    fDummy2             0           unsigned long
    wReserved           0           unsigned short
    XonLim              2048        unsigned short
    XoffLim             512         unsigned short
    ByteSize            8 '\b'      unsigned char
    Parity              0 '\0'      unsigned char
    StopBits            0 '\0'      unsigned char
    XonChar             17 '\x11'   char
    XoffChar            19 '\x13'   char
    ErrorChar           0 '\0'      char
    EofChar             0 '\0'      char
    EvtChar             0 '\0'      char
    wReserved1          0           unsigned short
```

Comment: First validate the sender by using some serial terminal, for example, serialterm.exe. If sender is OK, the problem is in your code, which you don't show. Read this classic serial communications article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx

Comment: I tried using hyperterminal. It works fine for hyperterminal.

Comment: So the logic goes: If you can receive in hyperterminal all the characters transmitted, then the transmitter code appears to work and you need to focus on the receiver code. You will have to edit a MCVE of the receiver code into your question to stand any chance of getting detailed help.

Comment: The problems are: (1) You haven't posted any code for evaluation (even after this was pointed out to you).  (2) the brief descriptions of the code indicates that it is inefficient programming because only one byte is read per syscall.

Comment: @sawdust I added a code snippet for the reference. This is at receiver's end.

Comment: Your timeout values seem way too large. try shorter timeouts.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036716/serial-comm-using-writefile-readfile

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your loop doesn't get the characters read out quite fast enough, so that by the 115th time, a new character is already overwriting the last one that is being read out too late.
To test this, you can add a very short delay between characters on the transmitter side, then see if the receiver acts differently.

Comment: I am writing all bytes at once. No loop is used at transmitter side.

Comment: The comment is about the RECEIVE loop not reading the characters out fast enough, not the transmitter. If you add a delay between transmitting characters, and the receiver starts receiving all the characters, then this points at the receiver code not working fast enough for the full speed transmit rate. You could achieve the same thing by e.g. halving/quartering  the tx/rx baud rate, as a test. What baud rate are you using?

Comment: Sure, I will try with lesser baud rate. I am using 9600.

Comment: The transmitter writes a stream of data at once. Not a character at a time. Adding delay between transmitting stream is not feasible as per my understanding.

Comment: @pkthapa *"The transmitter writes a stream of data at once"* -- Wrong.  You mentioned that you're using RS-232, which is an asynchronous serial protocol.  Asynchronous means it's not a *"stream of data"*, but really is *"a character at a time"*.

Comment: You have written the code in the transmitter yourself, then it should be in your power to change it to send a one-character string instead of a 115-character string, then pause for a time like maybe10ms, then send the next one-character string. Sound possible?

Comment: I increased the baud rate to 115200. Now receiver is able to receive 255 bytes of data only even if I write 1000 bytes of data. Although no delay is used, 255 bytes of data can be read. But what about the remaining? How can I get all 1000 bytes of data?

Comment: @barny I figured out. It was an incorrect code at transmitter's end. The transmitter, after sending, was not waiting for the data to be completely sent. WaitEvent is implemented at transmitter's end. This event ensures that all data are completely sent before starting sending of another data. Hope I am clear in explanation.