# Serial communication c++

Tags: c++, winapi, embedded, avr

I'm trying do some serial communication between my pc and an arduino ATmega2560

First the microntroller's program :

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.write('A');
}
```

The arduino program is very basic, his aim is to check the next program which is on the pc.

The main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SerialPort.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SerialPort port("com3", 9600);

    while (1)
    {
        //Receive
        unsigned char dataR;
        port.receive(dataR, 1);
        cout << dataR << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The SerialPort.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

class SerialPort
{
public:
    //Constructors
    SerialPort();
    SerialPort(const char* port, unsigned long BaudRate);

    //Initialization
    void Initialize(const char* port, unsigned long BaudRate);

    //Serial I/O
    void receive(unsigned char &data, unsigned int byteSize);
    void transmit(unsigned char *data, unsigned int byteSize);

    //State
    void connect();
    void disconnect();
    bool isConnected();

    //Destructor
    ~SerialPort();

private:
    HANDLE handler;
    bool isConnect;
};
```

And the SerialPort.cpp :

```
#include "SerialPort.h"

/*Constructors*/
SerialPort::SerialPort()
    : isConnect(false) {}

SerialPort::SerialPort(const char* port, unsigned long BaudRate)
    : isConnect(false)
{
    Initialize(port, BaudRate);
}

/*Initialization*/
void SerialPort::Initialize(const char* port, unsigned long BaudRate)
{
    handler = CreateFile(port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (handler == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR!::Error during opening port" << port << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    DCB serialParameters;
    if (!GetCommState(handler, &serialParameters)) /*Get com parameters*/
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR!::failed to get current serial parameters" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    serialParameters.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
    serialParameters.BaudRate = BaudRate;
    serialParameters.ByteSize = 1; /*8 bit data format*/
    serialParameters.StopBits = TWOSTOPBITS;
    serialParameters.Parity = PARITY_NONE;

    if (!SetCommState(handler, &serialParameters)) /*Send modified com parameters*/
    {
        std::cout << "ALERT!:Failed to set THE Serial port parameters" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    isConnect = true;
    PurgeComm(handler, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
}

/*Serial I/O*/
void SerialPort::receive(unsigned char &data, unsigned int byteSize)
{
    ReadFile(handler, &data, byteSize, NULL, NULL);
}

void SerialPort::transmit(unsigned char *data, unsigned int byteSize)
{
    WriteFile(handler, data, byteSize, NULL, NULL);
}

/*State*/
void SerialPort::connect()
{
    isConnect = true;
}

void SerialPort::disconnect()
{
    isConnect = false;
}
bool SerialPort::isConnected()
{
    return isConnect;
}

/*Destructors*/
SerialPort::~SerialPort()
{
    if (isConnect)
    {
        isConnect = false;
        CloseHandle(handler);
    }
}
```

I've an issue with this program : I don't receive the right data. Where I should get on the terminal

```
A
A
A
...
```

I get weird characters made of ? in a square

I hope you understood my problem
Thanks

Comment: and you not check any errors. may be your `ReadFile` fail for example (use both 0 in 2 last parameters is error)

Comment: This is the new receive method following your comment RbMn :

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake.... The new method is 
 void SerialPort::receive(unsigned char &data, unsigned int byteSize)
        {
        DWORD read;
        ReadFile(handler, &data, byteSize, &read, NULL);
        std::cout << read << std::endl;
       }

Comment: And  it says that one byte is read, also I get the same character printed

Comment: Perhaps the code from this old answer will be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037377/179910

Comment: If you're getting garbage characters continuously, you most likely have an incorrect baud rate, parity, start/stop bits, etc. Have you proven than the settings in the Arduino are what you expect, and have you tested this with the Arduino serial console or some other serial communications program that is known to work?

Comment: Hi, I finaly fix it by replacing  the serialParamters.DCBLength = sizeof(DCB) by serialParamters.DCBLength = sizeof(serialParamters)

Comment: @martantoine :  That makes no sense; `sizeof(DCB) == sizeof(serialParamters)` - either should work; what else did you change? `ByteSize` is my bet, since that is certainly incorrect.  However when you think you have solved your problem, post an _answer_ to your own question and mark it as the accepted answer (unless there is another answer you think is better).  By posting a comment rather than an answer - others may unnecessarily continue to post answers - so you will be wasting their time.

Answer (score 2):

The `DCB` `ByteSize` parameter is in *bits*.  You have specified a UART frame with one data bit - which is not supported by the hardware at either end.

For a conventional N,8,1 data frame, use

```
        serialParameters.ByteSize = 8 ;
        serialParameters.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT ;
        serialParameters.Parity = NOPARITY ;
```

`ByteSize` is perhaps a misleading name.  It defines the number of *bits* between the start and stop bit in an UART frame.  Most commonly this is 8, but for pure ASCII data transfer 7 might be used - historically at least.

The Atmel AVR UART supports frames with 5 to 9 data bits.  The PC's UART may be virtual, but will typically be compatible with the 16550 UART, which supported 5 to 8 bit data frames, however these days you are more likely to be using USB-Serial adapter, and the UART on the USB/Serial bridge may not support all 16550 modes - the common FTDI232R for example only supports 7 or 8 bit frames, while Prolific PL2303 supportts 5 to 8.  It probably pays to avoid unconventional frames and stick to N,8,1 if you want to be sure it will work on a range of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Arduino documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin) on `Serial.begin()` (emphasis added):

> An optional second argument configures the data, parity, and stop
>   bits. The default is 8 data bits, no parity, **one stop bit**.

I see this in your code (with no second parameter):

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

and this

```
serialParameters.StopBits = TWOSTOPBITS;
```

I think that may be your problem.

Comment: Too many stop bits on the sending end are normally not a problem. *Expecting* two stop bits and being sent only one, however, is.

Comment: you could have 100 stop bits and it would work just fine.  wrong number of data bits though and...

Comment: Yep, technically this doesn't solve his problem, until he sends data the other direction. I missed the data bits!