# C++ Serial Port code for receipt printer application

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am using an EPSON TM-U220D printer to print some receipts using my C++ application.
Printer connected to PC via Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge **(DB25 to USB)** and I have also installed the Silicon Labs Windows driver.

I was able to detect the printer on COM6 and when I try to write a simple "Hello", it doesn't print any.
When it is powered ON, I see "paper out" LED glowing, however if I connect 'putty' or 'tera term' or 'docklight', I see the printer gets initialized (paper moves a line) and the "paper out" LED goes off.
Also I was able to print from the above serial communication applications.

Below is my code snippet.
Kindly help me what could be wrong.
Not sure if the port setting is enough as it is DB25 connector.

BTW, are there any best c++ libraries available for such printer applications?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Define the five bytes to send ("hello")
    char bytes_to_send[6];
    bytes_to_send[0] = 104;
    bytes_to_send[1] = 101;
    bytes_to_send[2] = 108;
    bytes_to_send[3] = 108;
    bytes_to_send[4] = 111;
    bytes_to_send[5] = 0x0A;

    // Declare variables and structures
    HANDLE hSerial;
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };

    // Open the highest available serial port number
    fprintf(stderr, "Opening serial port...");

    hSerial = CreateFile(
        L"\\\\.\\COM6", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");

    // Set device parameters (38400 baud, 1 start bit,
    // 1 stop bit, no parity)
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting device state\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if (SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting device parameters\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    // Set COM port timeout settings
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    if (SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting timeouts\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    // Send specified text (remaining command line arguments)
    DWORD bytes_written, total_bytes_written = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "Sending bytes...");
    if (!WriteFile(hSerial, bytes_to_send, 5, &bytes_written, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d bytes written\n", bytes_written);

    // Close serial port
    fprintf(stderr, "Closing serial port...");
    if (CloseHandle(hSerial) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");

    // exit normally
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [softwarerecs.se] for recommendations, as recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: What happens when you create a text file, with your "Hello\n", then use a command prompt to send it to the printer (COM6)?  I would do this task to verify communications with the printer.  You may want to append "\r\n" to the text. You may have to configure COM6 before you do this.

Comment: When you successfully connect with Putty (etc.) what baud rate are you using? You code contradicts itself--comment says 38400, but code actually uses 9600.

Comment: Hard to be sure but here's one of my old answers that has a few bits that may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037377/179910